# Host private Maven repository using generic WebDAV

Tags: maven, grails, gradle

I'm wondering if it possible to run a private Maven repository using a simple WebDAV?

[Apparently, you can use an FTP server](https://stuartsierra.com/2009/09/08/run-your-own-maven-repository).

Long story short, I don't have the necessary rights to install Artifactory our server (plus it's also quite low on resources). Thus, I have setup a basic WebDAV dedicated to being a Maven repository.

I'm getting publishing [errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35776170/publishmavenpublicationtomavenrepository-failed-java-lang-nullpointerexception) (grails plugin publishing) and was wondering if it was due to WebDAV. If it turns out that it'll never work, I'll just remove this post and my errors post.

Comment: Artifactory has extremely low demands for resources (in fact, you can run it on RaspberryPi). Re the rights, what kind of rights do you have that you can run a WebDAV share but can't run Artifactory?

Comment: @JBaruch I have the rights to modify Apache/Tomcat/SVN configuration, thus easily enable a WebDAV. With this said, it just dawned on me, I can use an existing Tomcat (rather than install the RPM like I did in my local VM) to drop the war in, along with the basic necessary configuration and I should be done? Still curious to see if it's possible to run using a basic WebDAV.

Comment: Yes, "drop the war" is all you need. 
And no, Maven repo over webdav sucks BIG BIG BIG time. The maven webdav wagon is not recommended (unstable and what's not). Don't go on this path, you'll suffer.

Comment: I agree with JBaruch, WebDAV is a complicated thing. Its complex - most tools don't really work with each other. I ran a maven repo for quite some time with FTP and SSH - that worked quite well. But the comfort of Maven Repository like Artifactory or Nexus compared to that manual labor is unbeatable. The time these save should allow you to buy a simple server already. Use a maven repository manger / proxy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our team decided to start using Artifactory.